# How to open document in Edit mode from InfoPath form

Tags: 2010, document-library, infopath

I have an custom SPList that has a Hyperlink field pointing to a document in a document library.
The custom SPList has custom InfoPath forms for View and Edit.
To open the document in edit mode, SharePoint has an onclick event that makes the document open in Edit mode.

```
return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE', 
'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3','1', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments','','','',
'1','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff','','')
```

My question is, how to have the same behavior for the HyperLink field that is used in the InfoPath form.
The desired effect is that when a user opens the InfoPath form and  clicks on the hyperlink field to the document, the document opens in Edit mode.